# How to search in XML bound Listbox?

Tags: wpf, xml, binding, listbox

I have populated my listbox1 with xml data(XML Binding WPF).I do have a textbox which should filter the values populated in my listbox.Since i am binding from XML i can't use IndexOf function or listbox1.items[i].ToString() in a for loop.

Any Idea How to make it possible??

Comment: Did you find the answer posted below to be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

If your listbox is bound to a collection that inherits from IList, you can obtain a ListCollectionView in your code behind as follows...

ListCollectionView lcv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lv1.ItemsSource) as ListCollectionView;

where 'lv1' is the name of your items control.  Once this is obtained, you can set its 'Filter' property with a predicate like this...

lcv.Filter = (obj) => Convert.ToInt32(obj)%2 == 0; // select even numbers only

The predicate can take the form of a lambda expression that will be evaluated for each of the ojects in your collection. In your case, the predicate would compare each member of the collection to the value in your textbox and return a result. It can only return true or false...